# How we get the device type (phone, tab, desktop) of the react-native app without using package?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to get the device type(phone, tablet or desktop) in a react-native app but without using any package

Right now I'm using "Platform" from react-native and getting this output:

```
{
  "Model": "abc",
  "reactNativeVersion": {
    "minor": 71,
    "prerelease": null,
    "major": 0,
    "patch": 4
  },
  "Version": 31,
  "uiMode": "normal",
  "Release": "12",
  "Fingerprint": ".....",
  "Serial": "unknown",
  "isTesting": false,
  "ServerHost": "localhost:8081",
  "Manufacturer": "...",
  "Brand": "..."
}
```

but there is no field which gives me information about the device type: means "mobile", "tab", "desktop" etc...

So, if there is no direct solution for this in react-native please suggest to me how can I get this value either by native solution means in android or iOS.
Here I just want a custom solution instead of packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device type (phone, tablet, desktop) of the React Native app using the Dimensions module provided by React Native. The Dimensions module allows you to get the dimensions of the screen and, by extension, the device type. Here is an example,

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

if (width < 768) {
  console.log('This is a phone');
} else if (width >= 768 && width < 1024) {
  console.log('This is a tablet');
} else {
  console.log('This is a desktop');
}
```

or

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const deviceType = Platform.OS === 'ios'
  ? Platform.isPad ? 'tablet' : 'phone'
  : Platform.isTV ? 'tv' : 'unknown';

console.log(`This is a ${deviceType}`);
```

or

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const aspectRatio = height / width;

let deviceType = 'phone';
if (aspectRatio > 1.6) {
  deviceType = 'tablet';
} else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
  deviceType = 'desktop';
}

console.log(`Device type: ${deviceType}`);
```

Comment: with Dimensions, how can I handle the landscape mode of the screen, do I need to create separate if-else conditions for that as well, also is there any way which reduces this many if-else statements?

Comment: @KaranRampal If you rotate the screen, the screen width changes, and the default behavior of responsiveness considers it to be a larger device.

Comment: @KaranRampal try the third one